# Blank windows explorer windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

For some reason, my windows explorer windows now only show blank:

[image]

Every time I open a new explorer window, I get the above blank screen with a never-ending "loading" cursor (arrow with spinning blue circle).The computer is still mostly functional, but I cannot see anything. I cannot click the rex X to close the windows either.

Any ideas what is causing this? I've tried restarting multiple times, restarting explorer, and ran `sfc /scannow`. All other articles are pointing to just re-installing the OS =/

Comment: Do you have any removable disks installed?  I have only ever seen this when there was.

Comment: @Ramhound - I do have a DVD RW Drive installed. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Longshot, but check to see if the Remote Procedure Call service is running. Many years ago I disabled that and got bizare nonsense like this. Unfortunately, if it is RPCSS and it is for some reason not functioning correctly, that means Windows has been badly corrupted and you should probably reinstall anyway.

Comment: In my Services tab of Task Manager, RpcSs is running. Might be time to reinstall OS?

Comment: @FillipPeyton: I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform a repair install or at least boot in winpe and run in its cmd "dism /offline /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /restorehealth" (in dism 6.2 and later)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost a decade old lol, but the only page on the internet with the exact problem that I have.
I found the cause of this and somewhat acceptable solution.

At least in my case, this is caused by the Themes service.
When i stop the Themes service, Windows looks like it's back to Windows 98 or whatever, but Windows Explorer finally loads and I can use it without any issues.

As for solving it completely, fixing the Themes service or whatever is the root cause of this problem, I'm also getting the "reinstall Windows" as a suggested solution when I search for this issue or ask AI (ChatGPT).
Modern times huh.

Actually the way I found a solution was that I booted Windows in the Safe Mode. There I found that Windows Explorer is running without any issues, so I figured that either a driver or a service is causing this issue. That's when I asked ChatGPT which services Windows Explorer uses. It mentioned several and when I saw description of the Themes service, it was so on point with my problem. I loaded Windows into normal mode, disabled the Themes service and voilà, Windows Explorer finally loaded my drives, files and everything.